# How to access the angular filter value in node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to access the value in node js using req.body which is in ng-model, actually my ng-model is having a angular js filter,I need to get that filter value from the input field in node js using req.body, I paste my ng-model code snippet here, please help me to resolve

```
    <input type="disable" ng-disabled="true" class="form-control"
           name="count" ng-model="table.fields | mysum">
```

**angular filter**

```
app.filter('mysum', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var sum = 0;
    items.forEach(function(item) {
     if (item.item_count) {
         sum += item.item_count;      
      }     
    })
    return sum;
  }
})
```

Comment: You can't use `ng-model` with a filter -- `ng-model` needs to bind to property.

Comment: @ExplosionPills can you please tell how can I access the filter in ng-model have any idea

Comment: I think you should `$watch` for the model change and update the model value

Answer (score 0):

This would be your DOM, you can't apply filters to ng-model.

```
<input type="disable" ng-disabled="true" class="form-control"
           name="count" ng-model="table.fields">
```

And in your controller code, do something like this. Inject `$filter` as dependency in your controller.

```
$scope.table = {};
$scope.table.fields = $filter('mySum')($scope.table.fields);

//watch for updated value... .
$scope.$watch('table.fields', function() {
    //watch for changes and do something... 
});
```

Comment: how can I send that to node express like req.body to store that value in mysql table

Comment: if I want to watch this field means 
<input type="number" ng-model="table.fields[$index].item_count" class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>
should I igve like this in my watch 
$scope.$watch('table.fields[$index].item_count', function(){});
is the above one is correct